# Changing owners on secondary drive

Tags: 22.04

Today I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, and it looks like I missed a step; all but one of the folders on my secondary drive are inaccessible, appearing to be owned by my previous OS installation/build. How do I reclaim ownership of the locked folders stored on this drive?

Answer (score 1):

After much bashing my face against the wall, it looks like I figured it out.

1. `sudo bash, password`
2. `chown -R username:GID /media/oem/Extra\ Drive\ 1/`

I already knew my username, so that was easy. To get the GID, I issued command **id** to view both username and GID. I now appear to have full access to my files as my non-root user. I clearly have no idea what I'm doing, but learning.  ;)